# How to automatically clear terminal in Visual Studio Code when running the file on terminal?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, terminal

is there a way to configure VS Code to automatically clear the terminal right before I run a Python file, for example? I searched a lot for that but without success. Whenever I try to run a file in terminal, previous runs are still there in the terminal, and it gets kinda confusing. Notice that I want to clear the terminal when I run the code in terminal (i.e. when I click the play button), not when I run with debugging. My idea is to always have the terminal empty when I run a file. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Currently in VS Code, it does not automatically clear the terminal data settings, but you could use the command "`clear`" in the VS Code terminal to clear the previous output data, or click the'kill' icon to delete the current terminal and use the shortcut key Ctrl+Shift+` to open a new VS Code terminal.